# no file-saving after AIR Update

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, harman

I updated my air app from air32 to latest harman´s air50.

After the update, files can no longer be saved on Android.

```
var myFile: File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("/mnt/sdcard/Tfzf Helfer/activation.tfzfhelfer");
    var fs: FileStream = new FileStream();
    fs.open(myFile, FileMode.WRITE);
    fs.writeUTFBytes(dateiname);
    fs.close()
```

permission in the xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: You cannot create your own subdirs or files in root of external storage. Use an existing public directory instead like Documents or Download.

Comment: same with 
var myFile: File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("/mnt/sdcard/Documents/Tfzf Helfer/activation.tfzfhelfer");

Comment: You should first create those subdirectories before you try to save a file in a non existing directory. Also tell Android version of used device.

Comment: found the solution, works without "/mnt/sdcard"

Answer (score 0):

You can update the code in below :

```
var myFile: File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("Documents").resolvePath("Tfzf Helfer/activation.tfzfhelfer");
var fs: FileStream = new FileStream();
fs.open(myFile, FileMode.WRITE);
fs.writeUTFBytes(dateiname);
fs.close()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).